# How to intent from activity to specific fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I want to send an intent from one activity to a specific fragment like this picture, and fragment is in the fragmentactivity (fragmentactivity includes five fragments). I don't have any idea to implement it.
[image]

Comment: What you actually want to do? Your question is not understandable.

Comment: what you mean by "intent"

Comment: Please specify more clear , not able to understand .

Comment: Post your code please

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what do you mean by "to intent from activity to specific fragment". So I just assume you want to show/navigate to your fragment in your activity. Here's the simple code:

```
//show your fragment inside your activity
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
getIntent().putExtra("KEY", "Value"); //pass data to your fragment
transaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.IDofYourLayoutToBeReplaced, fragment);
transaction.commit();

//in your fragment, retrieve the data
String yourVariable = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY");
```

or to better understand, you can check [this link](https://dzone.com/articles/visualization-android-activity)